# Yii2 - Use two submit buttons for different controllers

Tags: php, button, input, yii2, submit

I want to create two submit button in my form. The first button (I use `Html::submitButton`) link to actionCreate in Controller redirect to index. I want to redirect the second button to its form but it doesn't work. Here is my second button:

```
<?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>  Save', ['simpan'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

and this is my actionSimpan in Controller

```
public function actionSimpan()
{
    $model = new Armada();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        // get the instance of the uploaded file 
        $imageName = $model->NAMA_ARMADA; 
        $model->photo = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'photo');
        $model->photo->saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->photo->extension);

        //save the path in the column 
        $model->IMG_ARMADA = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->photo->extension; 
        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I tried the `Html::submitInput` but it doesn't work. What should I do to make it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the `data-method="post"` to your anchor and it will submit the form automatically, no need to add any javascript. Change your anchor definition to the one below and you will see it start asking for the empty inputs of the form means triggers validation too and after validating it submits.

```
<?php

echo Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>  Save', ['simpan'], [
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
    'data' => [
        'method' => 'post'
    ]
]);
?>
```

Comment: I am not able to get the name can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66963449/6854117) related to it?

Answer (score 0):

Button:

```
<?= Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>  Save', ['simpan'], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'simpan-submit-btn']) ?>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$('#simpan-submit-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var submitUrl = $(this).attr('href');

  var form = $('form').eq(0); // change selector if you need
  form.attr('action', submitUrl);
  form.submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. the form just refreshed and didn't save any value.

Comment: @unicornous the question was on sending the form to another action, so it is.

Comment: I am not able to get the name can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66963449/6854117) related to it?

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure to place your submit button inside the form tags (using Html::submitButton).

If this is not the problem, check if the model is saving using:

```
if (!$model->save()) {
    var_dump($model->getErrors());
    die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is pass the params to the submit link:

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('common', 'Export to XLSX'), Url::toRoute(['xlsx-export']), [
            'class' => ['btn', 'btn-info', 'btn-sm'],
            'data' => [
                'method' => 'get',
                'params' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::toArray($modelSearch),
            ]
    ]); ?>
```